# Query to insert values in a column, according to the value of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a empty column, and I want to insert values in this column according to the value of another column, something like that:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(color)
VALUE('blue')
WHERE number = 1
VALUE('red')
WHERE number = 2
VALUE('green')
WHERE number = 3
```

I know this query not work, it's just to exemplify what I want :)

Comment: use UPDATE instead insert adds **only** new rows and doesn't have a WHERE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an UPDATE, not an INSERT

See example

> ```
> CREATE tABLE table_name (`number` int , color varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table_name(`number`)
> VALUES(1),(2),(3);
> ```

> ```
> SELEcT 
> * FROM table_name
> ```
>
> ```
> number | color
> -----: | :----
>      1 | null 
>      2 | null 
>      3 | null
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table_name 
> SET color = case
> when number = 1 then 'blue' when number = 2 then 'red'
> when number = 3 then 'green' else color end
> ```

> ```
> SELEcT 
> * FROM table_name
> ```
>
> ```
> number | color
> -----: | :----
>      1 | blue 
>      2 | red  
>      3 | green
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4818caab6082ed76ed5cb620de85f9d)*